# JSF only calls getters but never setters Composite Component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have been asked to write a JSF component that handles results paging. The component takes in a bean that implements an interface. At runtime, the getter methods are called but never the setters. Here is the code

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="pagableResultsBean" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- Question: We can't have a form inside of a form. Do we ecapsulate form operations here or 
    should the client handle them? -->
<cc:implementation>
    <c:set var="pagableResultsBean" value="#{cc.attrs.pagableResultsBean}" />
    <div
        style="background-color: #F0F3FA; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; height: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 2px 8px; position: relative; vertical-align: middle;">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <div style="float: left; width: auto;">
                Showing Results <h:outputLabel value="#{pagableResultsBean.showingRecordMin}" />  - <h:outputLabel value="#{pagableResultsBean.showingRecordMax}" /> of
                #{pagableResultsBean.totalRecordsNum} Results per Page:
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{pagableResultsBean.resultsPerPage}" onchange="$j(document).find('.pageBarSubmitBtn').click();">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{pagableResultsBean.resultsPerPageItems}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right; width: auto;">
                Showing Page #{pagableResultsBean.currentPageNum} of #{pagableResultsBean.totalPagesNum} Jump
                to Page
                <h:selectOneMenu id="_pagesMenu" value="#{pagableResultsBean.currentPageNum}" onchange="$j(document).find('.pageBarSubmitBtn').click();">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{pagableResultsBean.resultsPerPageItems}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{pagableResultsBean.goToFirstPage()}"> 
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-first.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{pagableResultsBean.goToPreviousPage()}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-previous.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{pagableResultsBean.goToNextPage()}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-next.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink style="position: relative; top: 3px;" action="#{pagableResultsBean.goToLastPage()}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrow-last.gif" />
                </h:commandLink>

            </div>
            <h:commandButton style="visibility: hidden;" styleClass="jsfHidden pageBarSubmitBtn"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

This is the interface that the backing bean implements:

```
public interface PagableResults {
    public int getShowingRecordMin();
    public int getShowingRecordMax();

    public ResultsPerPage getResultsPerPage();
    public void setResultsPerPage(ResultsPerPage rpp);

    public int getCurrentPageNum();
    public void setCurrentPageNum(int pageNum);

    public int getTotalPagesNum();
    public int getTotalRecordsNum();

    public List<SelectItem> getResultsPerPageItems();
    public List<SelectItem> getResultsPagesItems();

    public void goToFirstPage();
    public void goToLastPage();
    public void goToPreviousPage();
    public void goToNextPage();
}
```

And here is the snippet where the control is used

```
<h:form>
    <ndar:pagingBar pagableResultsBean="#{pageBean}" />
</h:form>
```

Can anyone see any reason why only the getters get called and not the setters?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to use `c:set` from the JSP JSTL Core Tag Library, this might not work well with the JSF and especially the JSF Composite Component system.

Have you tried to replace all instances of `pagableResultsBean`  with `cc.attrs.pagableResultsBean` as this would eliminate one possible reason of the error?

Also, put a Debugger on the set-method you think is not getting called - and verify whether it is really not called or just the html result looks like.

**Update 2014-12-31**

Also make sure to have a `h:messages` tag to the jsf to make sure JSF tells you of a possible conversion-error.

Comment: I have done as your suggested but this made no difference. Also I have thrown a break-point on the setter methods and confirmed that they are not getting called.